# eliminar 'NULL' SI viene dentro de un arreglo

Tags: php

¿Cómo puedo eliminar `NULL` si viene dentro del arreglo?
Estaba usando `unset()` pero no me funciona.

```
if (in_array('NULL', $conocimientosEspecificos)) {
  unset($conocimientosEspecificos['NULL']);
}
```

Este es mi arreglo de ejemplo:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "NULL"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
$linksArray = ["","Hola",2,"Prueba","",NULL,0,'null'];
$linksArray = array_filter($linksArray, 'strlen');
echo '<pre>' . var_export($linksArray, true) . '</pre>';

$basura = ['null'];
$linksArray = array_diff($linksArray,$basura);
echo '<pre>' . var_export($linksArray, true) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Si utilizas `array_filter` sin pasar `'strlen'` cuando encuentre valores `bool` como false o 0 los va a quitar.

resultado 1:

```
array (
  1 => 'Hola',
  2 => 2,
  3 => 'Prueba',
  6 => 0,
  7 => 'null',
)
```

resultado 2:

```
array (
  1 => 'Hola',
  2 => 2,
  3 => 'Prueba',
  6 => 0,
)
```

Comment: pero mi null es un string 'null'

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil ya edite mi respuesta hay te agregue la opción para tu caso. En el arreglo de basura puedes agregar todo lo que quieras que quite.

Answer (score 3):

Para filtrar `strings` vale el mismo método ya expuesto, sólo defines la condición en la función de filtrado.

```
$elArray = array(0=>'NULL');
$arraysinNULLString=array_filter(
  $elArray, function($valor){
    return $valor!='NULL';
});
```

Nota: el unset de tu ejemplo no funciona pues borra el elemento cuya clave es NULL

```
$conocimientosEspecificos = array(
  0  => 'NULL', 
  'NULL'=>'esto se va'
);
unset($conocimientosEspecificos['NULL']);
```

Answer (score 1):

array_filter — Filtra elementos de un array

```
<?php

$entrada = array(
             0 => 'foo',
             1 => false,
             2 => -1,
             3 => null,
             4 => ''
          );

print_r(array_filter($entrada));
?>
```

resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [2] => -1
)
```

Comment: pero que pasa con los demas valores si no los quiero eliminar y solo NULL

Comment: el segundo parametro de array_filter es una funcion para mejorar el filtrado (no sacar false por ejemplo) y si agregas como tercer parametro `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` la funcion recibe `$valor, $clave`

Comment: usa algo asi :array_filter($arr, function($var){return !is_null($var);} );

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WrVHNyPS